# How can I find out what time the user went inactive on console in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, display, event-log

I want to determine the moment when the user (me) went inactive -- "active" is defined as pressing a key or moving the mouse -- on a Windows 10 console. The easiest way it seems to me is to determine when the screen saver activates, the screen goes blank, and the console locks, and work backwards based on the timeout period, but I'm open to other ideas. Supposedly this is Event ID [4802](https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/kb/logon-logoff-events/event-id-4802.html) in the Event Viewer, but I've looked on two systems and neither one correctly seems to log this event. I've checked for Event ID 4800 (Workstation Locked) as well. Note: The system does not sleep but it *is* configured to lock on inactivity.

Comment: Do you have your system configured, so when a user is inactive, the system locks before going into a sleep state?

Comment: Only post the question you want answered. You've commented that "The real goal is to find out when the last user activity was...". I would not have used the event viewer to determine last user activity. That was a waste of time. If and when you edit your question I will edit / delete my answer / answers.

Comment: Ok, @somebadhat, re-reading my question in light of your answers, I can see the question was more open-ended and less exact than it should have been. Apologies for the trouble. I've reworked it. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5

What about doing a lastwritetime search with PowerShell?

```
gci -path $env:homedrive\USERS\_9doug -Exclude .android,AAMUpdater | dir -file -Recurse | ? { $_.FullName -notmatch 'responsive|scratch pad|.lnk|desktop.ini' } | sort lastwritetime -desc | select -ExpandProperty lastwritetime -f 1 | Out-File -filepath $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$a.txt -width 200
Write-output "

The lastwritetime was:" | Out-File -filepath $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$b.txt -append
Get-Content "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$a.txt" | Out-File -filepath $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$b.txt -width 200 -append
```

Comment: Close: I said _when_ the last user activity was, not _what_.

Comment: That is somebadscript ;-) I want to try that.

Comment: The OP commented: "The real goal is to find out when the last user activity was..."

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 64-bit

How to use the Windows 10 Event Viewer.

It depends on what you mean / what caused the PC to go blank and lock.  Is the display blank because a screensaver kicked in? Is the display off because a power setting was applied? Is the lock screen being presented because a Scheduled Task was run? Is the lock screen being presented because a power setting was applied? Figure out what you are looking for and look for it in the Event Viewer.

There is a lot of information in the event viewer, creating a [custom log](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson3/) will make searching for the timestamp easier.

When you find out what caused the display to go blank and / or the lock screen to be presented do a search engine search for "windows 10 event id for ...", search the event logs for the id and you will see the timestamp.

[image: screenshot of windows 10 event viewer]

Comment: I'm looking for the moment it timed out due to user inactivity. I want the time the screen goes blank, not the time the user returns and the lock screen appears. The real goal is to find out when the last user activity was before it went idle, but I can figure that out from when the screen goes blank.

Comment: Theoretically it should be 4802 (screen saver activated - https://www.manageengine.com/products/active-directory-audit/kb/logon-logoff-events/event-id-4802.html), but experimenting, it does not appear. I did a Custom View, selected Logged: Any Time, ticked Warning, Information, and Verbose, selected By Log: and ticked both top-level items, entered 4802 for the ID, chose <All Keywords>, <All Users> and <All Computers>. Zero hits. Tried many other permutations as well. Some yielded more hits than it could display, but I couldn't winnow them down.